# Safari cannot open the page because the server stopped responding

Tags: iis, windows-firewall, ios

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2, and have 2 web pages running via IIS.

The 1st one is on port 80 for HTTP, and the 2nd one is on port 16552 for an API interface.

I have opened all the connections for port 80 and 16552 for both UDP and TCP.

When connecting through a computer Windows 7 or 10 the connection works without issue each time, but when connecting through an iPhone or iPad I get "Safari cannot open the page because the server stopped responding".  This only happens the 1st time.  If I refresh the page it works.  It will continue to work for 20 or 30 minutes, but if I wait longer than that it will require me to refresh again.  Port 80 is access through Safari, and port 16552 is access through an app I created in Xcode.

Am I missing something in IIS or my firewall?  I have allowed both TCP and UPD both inbound and outbound in the firewall for both ports.

### When it works

[image: When it works]

### When page does not load

[image: When page does not load]

Comment: You shouldn't need UDP for HTTP.  Can you capture the packets of the ios session and see what's happening?

Comment: Yes, I just used Wireshark and ran it 2 times.  On the time it failed I got about 75% failed TCP (Black with Red).  When I refreshed and it worked I for 100% green with black.  I am not sure how to read anymore into the packets.  I'm googleing how to analyze the data now.

Comment: I'm going to add a screenshot from WireShark to the main post

Comment: You almost cannot find the cause with the information at hand. https://blog.packet-foo.com/2013/06/spurious-retransmissions/ Spurious Retransmission indicated that iOS side thought the transmission failed, while IIS did not agree. Unless you can dig out what exactly happened on iOS side (which is a black box so far), it is difficult to tell. You might try to install Firefox or Chrome on iOS though, to see if they experience the same issue.

Comment: I get the same results from Chrome on iOS.  You say it is difficult with the information on hand.  Is there anything I can do to gain the correct information, or is it not possible as the additional information would need to come from IOS?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up moving a couple of years later to Azure for the API and a Xamarin App for the front end.  I had the issue until I made the changes.