# Safari cannot open my website

Tags: node.js, uptime, safari

After two years of running a website (https://emocoes.org), today for the first time it does not open on Safari. It opens on other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, Opera), but on Safari I see:

> Safari Can't Open the Page
>
> Safari can't open the page "emocoes.org" because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes and try again.

[image: Safari error]

Following [Safari cannot open the page because the server stopped responding](https://serverfault.com/questions/931955/safari-cannot-open-the-page-because-the-server-stopped-responding) , I refresh the page, but see the same error.

The NodeJS logs do not show any GET request from Safari, and they do show them from Firefox. I clear the cookies and the cache from Safari and get the same error. If I open the page in a private window, then I can access the website, but I still need to fix this error for users who access the website on Safari. If the problem is specific to Safari and macOS, I will move the question to Apple.StackExchange.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

### update

Without having made further changes, the website is still failing on the same tab of Safari, and it works on the same instance of Safari but on a different tab. So the problem was likely from my computer and I will consider a reinstallation.

Comment: works for me on v15.3

Comment: If it works in private browsing then it's something to do with your instance of Safari.

Comment: I suggest leaving the question open as it could help others and invite @shearn89 to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works in private browsing then it's something to do with your instance of Safari. As per your update, this seems like a local issue not a server issue!